# How do I run a .sql script from Ruby that creates a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a sql script that creates a mysql database and tables. How do I connect to mysql and then execute my script from within Ruby?

I.e. I want the equivalent of "source ~/path/script.sql" but from within Ruby.

I have googled around a bit and was unable to find it. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Honestly, I'd just do `system "mysql < script.sql"`.

Comment: I don't know why you need a Ruby script to create an SQL database + tables though. There might be a better way to do what you're after. Can you tell us why you need that script?

Comment: I am just new to Ruby (3rd day) and I am wanting to accomplish this quickly so I can continue to focus on the CRUD part of ActiveRecord and unit testing. I figured executing the script would be the fastest way to accomplish that without getting too distracted.